# iOS 10 Push notifications in Xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios10, xcode7.1

Is there any way at all to handle iOS 10 notifications without having to upgrade to Xcode 8 and, possibly, have to rewrite whole swathes of code and re-instate all constraints (plus all the other scare stories)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, you are not able to do that. As with the new version of Xcode they will update the SDK also, so in case of Xcode 7 you don't have the updated SDKs.

Comment: Thanks Rajat - fingers crossed for the upgrade!

Comment: Go on, that would be great ;)

Answer (score 0):

**No You can't.**

If you are trying to develop on device which is having iOS 10.1.1 then you will have to get Xcode 8.1 You cannot handle it using any older Xcode not even Xcode 8.0.

For all lower iOS 10 version Xcode 8.0 is compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info